# Accessing username as supplied by curl -u in a request made to a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl

I am rewriting a legacy JSON API application in Rails 5 (in API mode, so we're using ActionController::API). For the sake of API consistency, the new application needs to be accessed like so:

`$ curl -u my-api-token: http://foo.bar/baz`

(Note that no password is provided).

From there, we ostensibly authenticate based on the API token and life is grand.

The issue I am having is my inability to access the `my-api-token` component of the request using Rails' `request` object in the controller (which is an `ActionDispatch::Request` object) or through the `params` hash -- in either case, `my-api-token` appears to be absent. The act of curling is otherwise successful, in that it hits the right endpoint and the right controller action.

The documentation for `curl` and for `ActionDispatch::Request` seem to be not particularly useful yet, and searching for `my-api-token` when inspecting the request object turns up nothing. Other threads in SO seem to be mostly about how to get `curl` working in the first place, rather than this particular use case.

What am I doing incorrectly? Or, perhaps better, what do I need to do differently to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are misunderstanding what the `-u` option does in cURL.  With the `-u` option, you are telling cURL to use Basic Authentication.  Thus, your API token is being sent in the HTTP `Authorization` header, not in the request params.

I see a few options to fix your problem.

The first option is to look in the request headers to extract the `Authorization` header value, base64 decode it, and you can then grab your API token.  I'm not very familiar with Rails, but it looks like this is fairly easy to do: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

The second option is to send the API token via GET params or a POST request.  I believe using a POST request is most common for authentication.

For example, using a POST request, you might do something like

`curl --data "token=API_TOKEN" https://example.com/resource.cgi`

Then you should be able to access the data in the request params.

Also, please consider using HTTPS.  With HTTP, any of the solutions I mentioned are susceptible to having your API token intercepted.  You can read this question to understand why this is so: https://superuser.com/questions/919859/is-curl-u-usernamepassword-http-example-com-secure